# "Second window" don't change a value where I am selected fields in combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, screen

```
 public ScoreboardAdminPanel()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            instance = this;
            foreach(var screens in Screen.AllScreens)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(screens);
            }
 
        }
```

```
  private void ButtonClickToShowScreen(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
             ScoreBoardShower.Location = Screen.AllScreens[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].WorkingArea.Location;
                   
        }
```

Filling the list of Combobox from all screens connected in system.

While I am selecting some screens from the combobox, I want to show my second form on that screen on button click.

But that work if I choose screen (For example "DISPLAY 1") from list once, after starting program and this value "saves" for all lifetime program, even when selected another screen from list.
And when I'm restarting this program and selected (For example "DISPLAY 2") happaning same.

P.S sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

Remember that you put Screen **Intances** into the Combobox.

You should simply be able to use the stored value directly:

```
var screen = combobox1.SelectedItem as Screen; // Just cast as correct type
ScoreBoardShower.Location = screen.WorkingArea.Location;
```

This should do the job.

Comment: that don't helpful for me, 'cause even where I'm changed the num in ScoreBoardShower.Location=Screen.AllScreens[num].WorkingArea.Location;. Using the program interface and input "1" or "2" for changed screens that not actually changed

Probably problem is that I cannot changed my  ScoreBoardShower.Location=Screen.AllScreens[num].WorkingArea.Location in realtime

Answer (score 0):

That didn't worked because ScoreBoardShower.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized; if change it on ScoreBoardShower.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal; works exactly

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).